# undefined on passing data as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting `undefined` at `user.login` and `user.bio`, unable to pass
data to `UserInfo` component from App.js. As Im not passing any state
its just props.

App.js

```
render() {
                return (
                  <div>
                    <nav className="uk-navbar-container uk-margin" uk-navbar="true">
                      <div className="uk-navbar-left">

                        <a className="uk-navbar-item uk-logo" href="/">  Github search  &nbsp;
                          <span uk-icon="icon: github; ratio: 2.2" className="uk-margin-large-right"></span>
                        </a>
                        <div className="uk-navbar-item  uk-navbar-right">

                          <form onSubmit={this.submitUser}>
                            <input className="uk-input uk-form-width-medium"
                              type="text" placeholder="Github UserName...."
                              id="username" onKeyUp={this.onChange} ref="username"></input>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <button className="uk-button uk-button-primary">Search &nbsp;
                            <span uk-icon="search" className="uk-margin-small-right"></span>
                            </button>
                          </form>

                        </div>
                        <div className="uk-navbar-item  uk-navbar-right"></div>
                      </div>
                    </nav>
                    <div className="uk-container-large">
                      <UserInfo name={this.props.username} />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                );
              }
```

UserInfo.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class UserInfo extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { userList: [] }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('in child =' + this.props.name)
        fetch('https://api.github.com/users/${this.props.name}')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(userList => {
                this.setState({ userList: userList })
                console.log('data is :' + userList);
            });
    }

    render() {
        if (!this.state.userList) {
            return (<div className="uk-child-width-1-3@s uk-grid-match">Loading...</div>)
        }
        const user = this.state.userList;

        return (
            <div className="uk-child-width-1-3@s uk-grid-match" uk-grid="true">

                <h3> {user.login} </h3>
                <h3>{user.bio}</h3>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default UserInfo;
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the **exact** error message.

Comment: Please add app.js relevant code for `this.props.username `

Comment: sounds like userList is an array, isn't it?

Comment: there is no error but in console i get this UserInfo.js:11 GET https://api.github.com/users/$%7Bthis.props.name%7D 404 (Not Found)

UserInfo.js:15 data is :[object Object]

Comment: class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { username: '', userList: [] };
    this.submitUser = this.submitUser.bind(this);
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }
  onChange(e) { console.log('here=' + e.target.value); }

  submitUser(e) {
    //  e.preventDefault()
    console.log('here is user=' + e.target.username)
   
  }

Answer (score 1):

the string concatenation when you call the fetch library is wrong, you can either use the backtick rather than the normal apex

```
fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${this.props.name}`)
```

or use a plain old concatenation

```
fetch('https://api.github.com/users/' + this.props.name)
```

otherwise `this.props.name` won't be interpreted as an actual variable and you will end up with a 404

[image]

Comment: in child = undefined

Comment: data is :[object Object]             these both im getting in console

Comment: the error is in the way you're invoking the api, you're not concatenating ${this.props.name} correctly

Comment: I used this now fetch('https://api.github.com/users/' + this.props.name) , but at   console.log('in child = ' + this.props.name) , I am getting  in child = undefined

Comment: when you invoke the component, here: <UserInfo name={this.props.username} /> , this.props.username is undefined, check when you get the value

Comment: my input changes each time so I cannot use props? as its immutable